# toString method for linked list to work with both normal and circular list

Tags: java

i am currently learning about linked-lists. I currently have a toString method that only works with normal lists, however i want to get it so it works with both normal and circular lists. Please could you provide me with some information on how i can do so. 
Many Thanks

```
public String toString(){
    String str = "";
    Node current = head;
    while(current != null){
        str = str + current.getItem();
        current = current.next();
        if (current != null){
            str = str + ", ";
        }
    }
    return str;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a circular list, the last node points to the first node. This means that for a circular list you need to stop your loop if you reach the head node a second time. This is a perfect opportunity to use a do-while loop. In case of a normal linked list, next will contain null so we can make it work for both types by having a double end-condition: if it is null or if it is the head node.

(Note: I'm assuming here that head contains null if the list is empty)

```
public String toString(){
    String str = "";
    if (head != null){
        Node current = head;
        do {
            str = str + current.getItem();
            current = current.next();
            if (current != head && current != null){
                str = str + ", ";
            }
        } while(current != head && current != null);
    }
    return str;
}
```

Also note that I kept your logic for having no trailing commas. I personally find it cleaner to just append a comma always, and trim the trailing comma after the loop by using a substring.

Comment: You can have a cycle in the middle of a list.

Comment: Isn't that a degenerate case? I'm pretty sure that's not supposed to happen in a correct implementation.

Comment: Yes, it usually is a degenerate case. Whether your answer is what the OP wanted depends on what he is actually asking for. If it's the ability to print properly formed circular lists, then this answer is good. If it's to make the method robust against any input lists (which may or may not contain a cycle), preventing endless loops, then this won't be quite enough.